# "Jacobian Conjecture" for $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, automorphism-groups, jacobian-conjecture

Is there exist a similar conjecture to the famous [Jacobian Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) with $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$ instead of 
$\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Namely, let $f$ be $\mathbb{C}$-algebra endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$, denote 
$f_i:= f(x_i)$, and further assume that the Jacobian of $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ is in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Is such $f$ an automorphism?

(I guess that first one should be familiar with the group of automorphisms of 
$\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}]$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232869/the-group-of-k-automorphisms-of-kx-1-ldots-x-n-x-1-1-ldots-x-n-1)).

**Edit:** I also wonder if there exists any nice connection between the Jacobian Conjecture and my above conjecture (which is not exactly phrased yet); for example, are the two conjectures equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Counterexample: the endomorphism of the product of two punctured lines (complement of the curve of equation $xy=0$ in the plane) given by $$(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{y},y^2\right)$$

We have
$$\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1f_1 & \partial_2f_1\\ \partial_1f_2 & \partial_2f_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{x}{y^2}\\ 0 & 2y\end{pmatrix},$$
so the Jacobian is constant equal to 1.

It's not an automorphism, since both $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ map to $(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks! Firstly, as you know, I did not impose the condition that the Jacobian is invertible. Do you think that there exists a similar (or additional) condition which will guarantee that $f$ is an automorphism?

Comment: Perhaps it is enough to assume injectivity of $f$ instead of invertibility of the Jacobian? or in addition to invertibility of the Jacobian? (In my original question there was no restriction on $f$, but then @YCor suggested $x_1 \mapsto 1$, so I commented that perhaps I should add either invertibility of the Jacobian or injectivity).

Comment: Or perhaps the right condition should be as follows: The Jacobian of $\{f_1,f_2\}$, call it $J$, is in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and the Jacobian of $\{f_1^{-1},f_2^{-1}\}$, call it $\hat{J}$, is in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. But it seems a little too restrictive. So perhaps the right condition should be that $J \hat{J}$ is in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$? (this allows non-invertible $J$'s).

Comment: About injectivity, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem (I haven't checked it works in this context, although it sounds likely at first sight). But it's clearly of a different spirit, because the Jacobian condition is some immediately checkable condition, while the injectivity is not.

Comment: Note that constancy of Jacobian is not necessary, even in 1-d: take $x\mapsto 1/x$, for example. A necessary condition is that the Jacobian be a monomial.

Comment: @ACL Indeed the Jacobian is not even invertible in this case.

Comment: Well, it is invertible. In the sense that it is a non vanishing  function on the torus.

Comment: Thanks; I was thinking of composition, but it's indeed irrelevant.

Comment: More generally, any isogeny of algebraic tori: $f\colon \mathbf G_m^n\to\mathbf G_m^n$ has an invertible Jacobian. (Proof: either by computation, or by remarking that there is an “inverse” isogeny, whose composition is $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to (x_1^d,\dots,x_n^d)$, where $d$ is the degree of $f$.) On the other hand, the first proof gives the clue to the initial question.

Comment: Consider a morphism $f\colon\mathbf G_m^n\to\mathbf G_m^n$. It is given by monomials $f_1,\dots,f_n$. Write $f_i(x)=\prod x_j^{a_{ij}}$. Then $Jf=\det(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)=\det( a_{ij} f_i / x_j ) = f_1\dots f_n / x_1\dots x_n \det (a_{ij})$. So either $Jf=0$ (and the image of $f$ is a subtorus), or $Jf$ is a nonzero monomial, and then $f$ is an isogeny.

Comment: @user237522: the point in ACL's last comments is that the endomorphism semigroup of the torus is considerably smaller than that of the affine $n$-space, so checking whether it's an automorphism is immediate (namely, you need that the matrix of exponents, which is in $\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbf{Z})$, belongs to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$)

Comment: Thank you very much YCor and ACL! very interesting discussion. I guess that YCor's last comment is actually the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232869/the-group-of-k-automorphisms-of-kx-1-ldots-x-n-x-1-1-ldots-x-n-1

Comment: In spirit yes. The MathSE question only considered automorphisms and the point is that they can easily be described. It does not consider endomorphisms, but it works in the same way.

Comment: Namely, for an arbitrary $k$-endomorphism $h$, $h_i=h(x_i)$ must be invertible (since $x_i$ is), so it is a monomial $x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_n^{c_n}$, $c_j \in \mathbb{Z}$ (an invertible element in $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n ,x_1^{-1},\ldots, x_n^{-1}]$ is necessarily a monomial $x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_n^{c_n}$, if I am not wrong).

Comment: More precisely, a nonzero scalar multiple of a monomial (in ACL's comment it's understood that a scalar multiple of a monomial is a monomial).

Comment: (Thanks!) Concluding that regardless of the Jacobian of $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$, there exist infinitely many endomorphisms which are not automorphisms, according to the matrix of exponents, as YCor explained in a comment above. In the above answer, $h_1=x_1^{1}x_2^{-1}$ and $h_2=x_2^2$, the corresponding matrix is not invertible in $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$, so $h$ is not an automorphism. This answers my question (I wonder if my edit is worthless or not).

Comment: @YCor The determinant Jacobian of your example is $2$ and not $1$. ;)

Comment: @Armandoj18eos yes you're right! fortunately it does not matter!

Comment: I know: it's only a typo. :)